# How to securely erase solid state drive in netbook running ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, ubuntu-netbook

I want to sell (or donate) my HP Mini 1000 netbook, but I am concerned about identity theft and securing personal information with the transition to a new user.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The netbook has a 16 GB solid state drive. I am under the impression that different methods are required to securely erase an SSD, compared to a traditional hard drive.

How do I do this and prepare this computer for sale (or donation)? It is not important whether the computer can still boot the operating system after this erase - only that an operating system can again be installed.

I have tried to read about this in many places on the web, including in askubuntu, but the process is never explained in sufficiently clear, jargon-free language. Or perhaps it is, but I still don't understand how to do this! Can I do this without procuring software? If I need to get software, what should I get?

Essentially, can anyone explain how I do this to someone who, you can assume, knows very little about computers, but can competently follow directions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, either HDDerase or Parted Magic can achieve this. If you create a Live USB with Parted Magic you should be able to do this quite easily.

Perhaps one of the following guides will help:

1. http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-securely-erase-an-ssd-drive/
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udxNL6sCuDQ
3. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/securely-erase-ssd-without-destroying/

If anything isn't clear to you, try being more specific in your question or comment on my answer.